# React Application not working after a fresh install

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, upgrade

I have been running a React SSR (Node and MongoDB backend) application without problems for over a year.  During that time I have been making updates and the application has worked fine.  The application is/was using Node 13.8.0 and I decided I needed to upgrade Node and other libraries.  I created a test area and installed Node 16.17 and could not get my application to work. I started getting the console log message shown below and the application would just sit at the log in screen. When I resorted back to my original version it too no longer worked and showed the same error.

I decided to uninstall all versions of Node and using NVM installed 13.8.0 only.  Still the same error.  Note that prior to running npm install I always remove package-lock.json file and node_modules folder.

Here is the output in the console log when run in Chrome

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:220:269)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:220:332)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1012:1)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1009:1)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:308:1394)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:425:35)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:756:1)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:973:1693)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:977:73)
    at r (browser.umd.js?8c0d:1:348)
    at Object.eval (browser.umd.js?8c0d:973:245)
signin:1 [DOM] Password field is not contained in a form: (More info: https://xxxx/9p2vKq)
client.js?0e57:96 [HMR] connected
```

When the app is run in Edge the split error is the same but the password note is gone and instead a different message appears.

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
signin:1
```

I then installed npm-outdated and ran it to get a list of the versions that were wanted.  I then updated only to the wanted versions.  Still the same error.

Here is the listing from npm Outdated

```
Package                     Current   Wanted  Latest  Location
@babel/core                   7.9.0    7.9.0  7.19.3  teachlearngame
@babel/preset-env             7.9.0    7.9.0  7.19.3  teachlearngame
@babel/preset-react           7.9.4    7.9.4  7.18.6  teachlearngame
@hot-loader/react-dom       16.13.0  16.13.0  17.0.2  teachlearngame
@lexical/code                0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@lexical/link                0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@lexical/markdown            0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@lexical/react               0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@lexical/rich-text           0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@lexical/utils               0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
@material-ui/icons            4.9.1    4.9.1  4.11.3  teachlearngame
babel-loader                  8.1.0    8.1.0   8.2.5  teachlearngame
body-parser                  1.19.0   1.19.0  1.20.0  teachlearngame
cookie-parser                 1.4.5    1.4.5   1.4.6  teachlearngame
express                      4.17.1   4.17.1  4.18.1  teachlearngame
file-loader                   6.0.0    6.0.0   6.2.0  teachlearngame
formidable                    1.2.2    1.2.2   2.0.1  teachlearngame
framer-motion                1.11.1   1.11.1   7.5.0  teachlearngame
helmet                       3.22.0   3.22.0   6.0.0  teachlearngame
lexical                      0.3.11   0.3.11   0.5.0  teachlearngame
mongoose                    5.13.15  5.13.15   6.6.2  teachlearngame
react                        17.0.2   17.0.2  18.2.0  teachlearngame
react-dom                    17.0.2   17.0.2  18.2.0  teachlearngame
react-hot-loader            4.12.20  4.12.20  4.13.0  teachlearngame
react-material-ui-carousel   2.3.11   2.3.11   3.4.2  teachlearngame
react-resizable              1.11.1   1.11.1   3.0.4  teachlearngame
react-router                  5.1.2    5.1.2   6.4.1  teachlearngame
react-router-dom              5.1.2    5.1.2   6.4.1  teachlearngame
react-swipeable-views        0.13.9   0.13.9  0.14.0  teachlearngame
uuid                          8.3.2    8.3.2   9.0.0  teachlearngame
webpack-cli                  3.3.11   3.3.11  4.10.0  teachlearngame
webpack-dev-middleware        3.7.3    3.7.3   5.3.3  teachlearngame
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "teachlearngame",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "A combination of teaching, learning and gaming",
  "author": "xxx xxxxxxx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "express",
    "mongodb",
    "node",
    "mern"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-classroom.git"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/shamahoque/mern-classroom",
  "main": "./dist/server.generated.js",
  "scripts": {
    "development": "nodemon",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.client.production.js && webpack --mode=production --config webpack.config.server.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./dist/server.generated.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "13.8.0",
    "npm": "6.13.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.9.4",
    "babel-loader": "8.1.0",
    "file-loader": "6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.6.1",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.2",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.19.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@hot-loader/react-dom": "16.13.0",
    "@lexical/code": "^0.3.11",
    "@lexical/link": "^0.3.11",
    "@lexical/markdown": "^0.3.11",
    "@lexical/react": "^0.3.11",
    "@lexical/rich-text": "^0.3.11",
    "@lexical/utils": "^0.3.11",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@material-ui/utils": "^4.11.3",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
    "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.98",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.4",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.10.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "bad-words": "^3.0.4",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "clsx": "^1.2.1",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.5",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.5",
    "formidable": "1.2.2",
    "framer-motion": "^1.11.1",
    "helmet": "3.22.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "lexical": "^0.3.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-auto-rotating-carousel": "^3.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.11",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.8",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-confetti": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-helmet-async": "^1.3.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.12.20",
    "react-material-ui-carousel": "^2.3.11",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.12.0",
    "react-render-to-string-async": "0.0.3",
    "react-resizable": "^1.11.1",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0",
    "react-ssr-adsense": "^1.0.1",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.13.9",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.6",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "url-parse": "^1.5.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0"
  }
}
```

Finally, here is the output from the npm install

```
npm install 2>&1 | tee log.txt

npm : npm WARN deprecated @material-ui/icons@4.9.1: You can now upgrade to @mui/icons. See the guide: 
https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install 2>&1 | tee log.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm WARN deprec...s/migration-v4/:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
npm WARN deprecated formidable@1.2.2npm : Please upgrade to latest, formidable@v2 or formidable@v3! Check these notes: 

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain 
circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated @types/bson@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. bson provides its own type definitions, so you do not need 
this installed.
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated

> @fortawesome/fontawesome-common-types@6.2.0 postinstall C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\TLGamer\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-common-types
> node attribution.js

Font Awesome Free 6.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc.


> @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@6.2.0 postinstall C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\TLGamer\node_modules\@fortawesome\fontawesome-svg-core
> node attribution.js

Font Awesome Free 6.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc.


> @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@6.2.0 postinstall C:\Users\jterr\Documents\NodeProjects\TLGamer\node_modules\@fortawesome\free-solid-svg-icons
> node attribution.js

Font Awesome Free 6.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com
License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License)
Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc.

npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @hot-loader/react-dom@16.13.0 requires a peer of react@^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN @material-ui/icons@4.9.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @material-ui/icons@4.9.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN framer-motion@1.11.1 requires a peer of react@^16.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN framer-motion@1.11.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-auto-rotating-carousel@3.0.2 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-auto-rotating-carousel@3.0.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hot-loader@4.12.20 requires a peer of @types/react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hot-loader@4.12.20 requires a peer of react@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hot-loader@4.12.20 requires a peer of react-dom@^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-material-ui-carousel@2.3.11 requires a peer of @material-ui/icons@^4.11.2 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-render-to-string-async@0.0.3 requires a peer of @types/react@^16.9.41 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-render-to-string-async@0.0.3 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.13.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-sitemap@1.2.0 requires a peer of react@^15.1.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-router-sitemap@1.2.0 requires a peer of react-router@^2.3.0 || ^3.2.1 || ^4.3.0 but none is installed. You must install 
peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-swipeable-views@0.13.9 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @lexical/yjs@0.3.11 requires a peer of yjs@>=13.5.22 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-ui-dots@2.0.2 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN material-ui-dots@2.0.2 requires a peer of react-dom@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN react-event-listener@0.6.6 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN webpack-cli@3.3.11 requires a peer of webpack@4.x.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

added 842 packages from 524 contributors and audited 849 packages in 62.685s

47 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

From what I can see, although many warnings, I do not see anything that indicates an error. Using developer tools all steps show a 200 code.  I looked through the code for use of "split" and commented the two places I was using it in code that would run prior to the login screen.  Still the same result.

Questions

1. What are possible causes for an application that was running, to stop running with a fresh install but no coding changes?
2. I have updated all libraries to the "wanted" version per npm-outdated but still get a lot of deprecation warnings.  Can these be causing the issue?
3. The messages from npm install include a lot of, ".. requires a peer of react@^16.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself."  My understanding is that these are recommended but not required.  Is that the case or do I need install these peer dependencies?
4. A lot of the peer dependencies are for libraries that I have already installed.  How can I have two versions of the same library installed?
5. If I do install peer dependencies, I would use --save-dev and they would show up as dev dependencies.  What happens when I move the code to production?
6. What happens when I later upgrade the libraries that have peer dependencies and the peer dependency is no longer required?  How will I know that?  Will I have to then uninstall it?  What is the drawback of not uninstalling when no longer needed?
7. Back to the original problem, why would an application that was running fine (no code changes) stop running after a fresh install?  Even if you have some possible reasons that I could investigate, that would be appreciated.
8. From the dev tools, if I select the "split" error line it points to the lines below.  I am not familiar with this code.  Can the cause of the error be determined from this?

The error in the bundle.js file is in the following bundle code

```
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var __webpack_module_cache__ = {};
/******/    
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        var cachedModule = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId];
/******/        if (cachedModule !== undefined) {
/******/            if (cachedModule.error !== undefined) throw cachedModule.error;
/******/            return cachedModule.exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = __webpack_module_cache__[moduleId] = {
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/    
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        try {
/******/            var execOptions = { id: moduleId, module: module, factory: __webpack_modules__[moduleId], require: __webpack_require__ };
/******/            __webpack_require__.i.forEach(function(handler) { handler(execOptions); });
/******/            module = execOptions.module;
/******/            execOptions.factory.call(module.exports, module, module.exports, execOptions.require);
/******/        } catch(e) {
/******/            module.error = e;
/******/            throw e;   ***<=  The error points to this line***
/******/        }
/******/    
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;
/******/    
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
```

9. Could the issue be related to a Chrome setting?
10. Another problem I am having is that expected Console log statements are not being printed to the console.  I have included a lot of statements but the only messages in the console are what I have shown above.  What could be blocking output to the console ?
11. See Note 3 below.  Does anyone know how to change and what to change the navigation agent to?

NOTE 1. The Password issue seems to be a Chrome issue as I do not have the Password issue when I run using Edge.  Instead I was getting a different message, "signin:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received."   I was able to make this message go away by removing the Norton Extension from Edge.  The
only extension on both Edge and Chrome is the React Developer Tools Extension.

Note 2. Other Stack Overflow problems talk about the password problem. I have tried autocomplete set to "off" and "current-password".  Below is what I currently have

```
        <TextField
          id="password"
          type="password"
          label="Password"
          className={classes.textField}
          autocomplete="off"
          value={values.password}
          onChange={handleChange("password")}
          margin="normal"
        />
```

Note 3: Using developer tools I see a navigation issue (see Issue below) that may be causing the application to stop.  Using the following steps I tried to change the agent.  Unfortunately each time I change and then check the agent reverts back to the default.

Does anyone know how to change and what to change the navigation to?

How to Change Your User-Agent on Chrome & Edge

1. Right Click Anywhere in Webpage > Inspect. Alternatively, you can use CTR+Shift+I on Windows, Cmd + Opt +J on Mac.
2. Choose More Tools > Network Conditions. ...
3. Uncheck Select Automatically Checkbox.
4. Choose One Among the Built-In User-Agents List.

Issue:
A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.

Comment: have you tried cleaning npm cache, `npm cache clean` or `npm cache clean -f`

Comment: would double check you reverted to previous node, `which node`, and that this is pointing to your nvm dir.

Comment: I had previously tried cleaning cache but tried it again using -f.  No change.

Comment: When all the problems started I uninstalled all of my Node versions.  When NVM did not uninstall I used the Windows uninstaller.  I also removed NVM and reinstalled NVM. 
Using NVM I installed the version of Node I had been using initially, 13.8.0.  I then applied the NVM use command.  No change.

Comment: I have looked at other Stack Overflow problems that indicate that the password issue can be resolved by adding, autocomplete to the password definition.  I have tried both, autocomplete="current-password" and autocomplete="off"  I will add my definition to the problem above

Comment: Using Developer Tools I see that an issue is occurring.  I will add it to the detail above as I cannot create comment large enough to describe it.

Comment: @GregBrodzik enough with cache clean commands. they are never useful

Comment: This might a problem with using latest browser. maybe try using an older version of the browser where the app used to work and verify that? plus try backtracking through the console error to find the origin of your TypeError. Also, try [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_type-checking-javascript) to type check your js code to figure out that any undefined behaviour that was as well.

Comment: can you check your `npm -v` is it the older (that NODE 13 uses) should be v6 I believe? As I had issues switching from node v12 directly to v16 aswell.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that almost the majority of your libs are out of date. Try updating all the packages to the latest version. Updating from 13 x to the latest version of Node is a big jump. Hope this solves this contradiction.

Comment: I did try updating to latest and unfortunately I have the same issue.  I reverted back to an earlier version that had been working, removed node_modules and package_lock and performed a fresh install.  Problems persisted so I think either it is a problem with a browser update or some other system issue.